# prove $(n) \supseteq (m)\iff n\mid m\ $ (contains = divides for principal ideals)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, divisibility, ideals

For non-zero integers $m$ and $n$, prove $(m) \subset (n)$ iif $n$ divides $m$,
where $(n)$ is the principal ideal. My attempt is following.

For non-zero integers $m$ and $n$, assume that $(m) \subset (n)$. Then, $mk \in (m)$ is also in $(n)$. This means that $\exists nh$ such that $mk = nh.$ Then, we have $m=nhk^{-1}.$

Assume that $n$ divides $m$ for non-zero $n$ and $m$. Then, $n = mk$ and the principal ideal of $n$ will be $(n)=\{ mkr\ |\ n,r \in \mathbb{Z} \}.$
Since $kr \in \mathbb{Z}$, clearly $(m) \subset (n)$. is this ok proof?

Comment: It *seems to be* you're talking of ideals in the ring $\;\Bbb Z\;$ , so (1) Why not to mention that ? Why did you tag this question "group theory" instead of ring theory?

Comment: $m=nhk^{-1}$ is - when we are dealing with integers - no guarantee that $n$ divides $m$. However we have $mk\in(n)$ for **any** integer $k$. So just do it with $k=1$. On the second part: if $n$ divides $m$ then $m=nk$ for some $k$ (not $n=mk$).

Comment: @drhab yeah sorry. So if I let $m=nk$, then $(m) = \{ nkr\ |\ k,r \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. So $(n)$ contains $(m)$. Is this good??

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You don't have to assume $R=\mathbb Z$. This holds for commutative rings too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $m,n\in\Bbb Z$. We wish to show that $\langle m\rangle\subset\langle n\rangle$ if and only if $n\mid m$.

First, suppose that $\langle m\rangle\subset\langle n\rangle$. Since $m\in\langle m\rangle$ it follows that $m\in\langle n\rangle$. That is, there exists a $k\in\Bbb Z$ such that $nk=m$. Hence $n\mid m$.

Conversely, suppose that $n\mid m$. To show that $\langle m\rangle\subset\langle n\rangle$, let $km\in\langle m\rangle$. Then, since $n\mid m$, there exists an $\ell\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\ell n=m$. It follows that $km=k\ell n\in\langle n\rangle$. Hence $\langle m\rangle\subset\langle n\rangle$.

Comment: Does the proof change in a PID? maybe just an $R$ instead of $\mathbb Z$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ (a_1,\ldots,a_j) \subseteq (b_1,\ldots,b_k)\!\!\overset{\rm\color{#c00}{U}\!\!}\iff a_1,\ldots,a_j \in (b_1,\ldots,b_k)\iff $

$$\iff \begin{bmatrix} a_1\\ \vdots\\ a_j\end{bmatrix}\,=\,\begin{bmatrix}c_{11} &\ldots &c_{1k}\\  \vdots &\ddots & \vdots\\ c_{j1}&\ldots &c_{jk} \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} b_1\\ \vdots\\ b_k\end{bmatrix}\ \ \text{for some }\ c_{i,j}\in R$$

OP is  case $\, j = 1 = k,\ $ i.e. $\ a_1 = c\, b_1\ $ for some $\ c\in R,\ $ i.e. $\ b_1\!\mid a_1,\, $ i.e.

$$\quad\  (b_1)\supseteq (a_1) \iff b_1\mid a_1\qquad {\bf [contains = divides]}$$

Here $\rm\color{#c00}{U} =$ universal property of ideal sum: $\, A_1+A_2 \subseteq B\!\iff\! A_1,A_2\subseteq B,\,$ for any ideal $\,B,\,$ i.e. the ideal sum is the smallest ideal containing the summands. Above is the special case when the summands $A_i = (a_i)$ are principal ideals.

$\!\!\begin{align}\text{For  proper containment:}\ \ (a)\supsetneq (b)&\iff (a)\supseteq (b)\text{ and not }(b)\supseteq (a)\\[.4em] 
&\iff\ \  a\ \ \mid\ \ b\ \ \text{ and not }\ \  b\ \ \mid\ \  a
\end{align}$

which means that $\,(a)\supset (b)\,$ properly $\iff\, a\mid b\,$ properly, i.e. the "proper" analog holds.

Comment: What you mean with $R$? Please be more specific...(I guess that $R$ can be a general ring but needed to be commutative), and when you take $j=1=k$ we earn $a_1=c_{11}b_1$ ...

Comment: @k1.M I presume $R\,$ is a commutative ring. and obviously I use the abbreviation $\, c = c_{11}\,$ to avoid ofuscatory notational clutter. Was that not clear? The downvote is ridiculous, but not surprising given the nonsensical downvoting nowadays.

Comment: Now that's clear...but observe that you should write the assumptions in the answer not in the comments...

Comment: @k1.M I expect the reader to have the mathematical maturity to make obvious sensible inferences (that's why it is a "hint").

Comment: what it means OP?

Comment: @Annet. Original Post(er),  either the initial post in a thread, or the author of it.