# Ideals of Unique Factorization Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, unique-factorization-domains

Let **R** be a commutative ring with unity such that **R[x]** is UFD. The ideal **(x)** of **R[x]** is denoted by **I**. Then pick the correct statements from below:
1. **I** is prime.
2. If **I** is maximal then **R[x]** is a PID.
3. If **R[x]** is a Euclidean domain then **I** is maximal.
4. If **R[x]** is a PID, then it is a Euclidean domain.

According to me third is wrong because Z[x] is a Euclidean domain but **I** is not maximal. What about the other options?

Comment: $Z[x]$ is not Euclidean. What do you get when you divide $x$ by 2?

Comment: It seems like *all four* are correct, so the question is a little strange.

Comment: yes all the options are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $R[x]/I \cong R$.
1-  $I$ is prime iff $R$ is domain.
2-  $I$ is maximal iff $R$ is field.
3- use (2) with the fact: [$R$ is a commutative integral ring, $R[X]$ is a principal ideal domain imply $R$ is a field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940443/r-is-a-commutative-integral-ring-rx-is-a-principal-ideal-domain-imply-r).
4- By the link above, $R$ is a field.